# Is $A\to \exp(A)$ injective- what is wrong with what I claim?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

During a test in Ordinary Differential Equations I was ask to determine whether or not $A\to \exp(A)$i is an injection, for $A$ over $M_{n\times n}$. I took $n=1$, $A=z$, so that $e^{z+2\pi ik}=e^z$ for any $k$, but it wasn't sustained, and I didn't quite understood the explanation which stated: "But we are over the real numbers- you are to translate the conclusion to the matrices with which we are working.". Does $M_{n\times n}$ means real only?, are ODEs just about real numbers? I didn't understand the "translation" part. I could really use your insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ODE's are definitely not only about real numbers, and $M_{n\times n}$ is ambiguous without specifying the field.  It could be that your instructor only uses $M_{n \times n}$ for $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$.

By "translation" presumably what is meant is that you are to take a real matrix $A$ such as $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr -1 & 0\cr}$ that has imaginary eigenvalues, so that $\exp(tA)$ is periodic for real $t$.

Comment: So this is how I was supposed to relate the complex numbers?